# change owl carousel items spacing after hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYuwj.jpg)I have owl-carousel in my code with images, when I hover over an image the image zooms in, the thing that I want to add is to make inactive items to spread apart when you hover over the active item.

this is the code I tried, but it's not working :

```
items.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    items.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (i !== index) {
        item.style.marginRight = '50px';
      } else {
        item.style.marginRight = '30px';
      }
    });
  });

  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    items.forEach((item) => {
      item.style.marginRight = '10px';
    });
  });
});
```

the carousel code is just a simple one :

```js
$(function() {
  var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 5,
   
    loop: true,
    nav: true
  });
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius : 50%;
}

.owl-carousel .item img {
  border-radius : 50%;
}

.owl-carousel .item:hover{
  transform : scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>



<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 2">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 3">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 4">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the picture that's attached is the result I want to achieve

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup as well?

Comment: @FiddlingAway  I added the whole code

Comment: Normally you would just find the element +2 or -2 index from the hovered element and set a class with  `margin-left: 2rem;` or right but this  carousel  does some strange things with elements here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a few minutes to rethink this;  The owl plug-in is doing some wrapping and other fun things to manipulate the DOM so we have to deal with that.  It wraps a parent element with class `own-item` so we get the hovered items parent and then deal with the siblings of that parent.

Because of the styling we cannot really add a left/right margin since that makes the whole carousel wrap oddly we have to use a `transformX`.  I did this by adding a data attribute to each of the parent siblings for the CSS we want to manipulate. This may not be exactly what you want on the direct `.next(hoverthing)` and prev siblings spacing but I believe you can build from this to add whatever you need to those as well.

```js
$(function() {
  const hoverthing = '.owl-item';
  const owl = $(".owl-carousel");

  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 5,
    loop: false,
    nav: true
  });

  owl.on('mouseenter', hoverthing, function(event) {
    const hoveredParent = $(this).closest(hoverthing);
    hoveredParent.next(hoverthing).nextAll(hoverthing).each(function() {
      this.dataset.mole = "right";
    });
    hoveredParent.prev(hoverthing).prevAll(hoverthing).each(function() {
      this.dataset.mole = "left";
    });
  }).on('mouseleave', hoverthing, function(event) {
    const hoveredParent = $(this).closest(hoverthing);
    hoveredParent.next(hoverthing).nextAll(hoverthing).each(function() {
      this.dataset.mole = "";
    });
    hoveredParent.prev(hoverthing).prevAll(hoverthing).each(function() {
      this.dataset.mole = "";
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.0);
}

.owl-carousel .item img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.owl-carousel .item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item[data-mole="right"] {
  transform: translateX(1em);
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item[data-mole="left"] {
  transform: translateX(-1em);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<div class="carousel-wrapper">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 2">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 3">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 4">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Image 5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```